# TypeScript Serialization

Tags: json, typescript, serialization

I'm having trouble storing a complex TypeScript object into the browser's storage, because it has to be serialized to a JSON string.

```
class ComplexObject {
  constructor(
    public date: Date,
    public child: SimpleObject,
  ) {}

  getContent() {
    return this.child.content
  }
}

class SimpleObject {
  constructor(
    public content: string,
  ) {}
}
```

While `const store = JSON.stringify(new ComplexObject(new Date(), new SimpleObject('test')))` produces JSON I am fine with, `const restored = JSON.parse(store)` will be a completely different object.

- `restored.date` is a string, not a `Date` anymore
- `restored.getContent()` produces a type error, as the function does not exist ob the object anymore

### Current Workarounds

I have tried some serialization libraries such as [cerialize](https://github.com/weichx/cerialize), which I have gotten to work. But all the libraries I have found require explicit marking of properties or at least classes with decorators such as `@Serialize()`.

This boilerplate troubles me, since I believe that TypeScript already posses all the information necessary to serialize and properly deserialize objects to JSON. Every line I have to add manually increases the potential for stupid bugs and is just plain not fun.

### Question

Are there libraries that do not require manual decorators but simply take a TypeScript object, do their thing to serialize it into a JSON string, and then offer a way of restoring the proper object from that string?

If no, why is it so hard to utilize TypeScript's information? What is the core difficulty?

Comment: Take a look at my answer for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16261119/typescript-objects-serialization/52237888#52237888

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just look at [generated code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20ComplexObject%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20date%3A%20Date%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20child%3A%20SimpleObject%2C%0D%0A%20%20)%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20getContent()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20this.child.content%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20SimpleObject%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20content%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%20%20)%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%7D). TypeScript class is compiled to JavaScript class. There is no any type information at runtime, so your question not about TypeScript, but [about JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608545/how-to-serialize-deserialize-javascript-objects). Libraries uses decorators, because decorators provide some type information at runtime.

The only way is to use static analysis. For example, run [Typedoc](https://github.com/TypeStrong/typedoc) with flag `--json`, parse output and generate some type info for serialization purposes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It's not very satisfying, but I understand a bit more clearly where the problem lies.